# How long does the wiki take to create package pages?

Tags: ros, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently waiting on several packages to be spidered for the wiki. For example, um6 and robot_upstart have both been in `hydro/doc.yaml` for almost three weeks with no wiki pages created. Have I not done something quite right?

Alternatively, if I just create the pages manually from the package template, will that create any problems down the road?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79821/how-long-does-the-wiki-take-to-create-package-pages?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki pages are not automatically created.  You need to create the wiki pages manually (use the basic template) and the automatic header information will be filled in within 3 days of submitting the documentation job.

How to create a package wiki page can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/PackageDocumentation

With a full guide to getting indexed here: http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-09-17**:
Okay, thanks! My recollection from the past is that pages were automatically created and then you went in and filled them in afterward. I must be muddled with something else, thanks.